# PowerShell 'less' tool

Tags: powershell, console

This is *not* a duplicate of the various other questions around this (I reviewed them and this was not answered in the ones that I saw). Those other questions revolve around `Out-Host -Paging` and `more` (even if they mention `less` in the question title).

To focus on this specific point, does anyone know of a PowerShell method of replicating the functionality of `less`, but on Microsoft Windows environments? i.e. giving us the ability to scroll down and up through a document (line by line with cursor keys or page by page with the PgUp / PgDn keys) to view help and other files (e.g. so that we can do `Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Full | less`).

This would be very useful. I am not after a 3rd party executable `less` tool (because that won't be pipeline enabled etc) for Windows (there are many of course). I believe that there is something in PSCX like this, but whenever I try to install that, I see lots of conflicts and I'm not sure to use `-AllowClobber` in case it breaks something else. Maybe on that though, if there is a `less` in there, has anyone been able to split out that function and use independently of PSCX?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Full | less` works just fine on Unix-like platforms, using the given platform's `less` utility (typically, `/usr/bin/less`) - no extra work needed.

> I am not after a 3rd party executable `less` tool (because that won't be pipeline enabled etc)

***Any* external program (utility) that reads from *stdin* (standard input) and outputs to *stdout* (standard output) is by definition *pipeline-enabled*, albeit invariably only with respect to *text***: data sent *to* such utilities is converted to text, and data returned *from* such utilities is interpreted as text.

**On *Windows*, only the - feature-limited - `more.com` pager is available by default** - see below.

However, **it is possible to *install* `less` on Windows**:

- If you have a Linux distro for the [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) installed, you can simply pipe to `wsl less`; e.g.:

  - `Get-Help Get-ChildItem | wsl less`
  - **Caveat**: <kbd>PageUp</kbd> / <kbd>PageDown</kbd> seemingly do *not* work when invoked from PowerShell, but <kbd>f</kbd> (forward) and <kbd>b</kbd> (back) provide the same utility.
- Otherwise, consider installing the [`less.exe` Windows console application](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/less/) (pick the version inside the most recent folder) that is part of the [GnuWin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/) project (the installer requires admin privileges).

  - This gives you normal <kbd>PageUp</kbd> / <kbd>PageDown</kbd> support.

Note: There's another port of `less` to Windows, which comes bundled with other utilities; haven't personally tried it: [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/).

**Caveats**:

- **`less` apparently expects UTF-8 input**, irrespective of the active OEM code page, and additionally only displays non-ASCII characters correctly if `[console]::OutputEncoding]` is set to UTF-8.

  - Therefore, both `$OutputEncoding` and `[console]::OutputEncoding]` must be set to UTF-8 (`[Text.Utf8Encoding]::new()`) for the display of non-ASCII characters to work properly. (In PowerShell [Core] v6+, `$OutputEncoding` defaults to UTF-8, but `[console]::OutputEncoding]` still reflects the system's OEM code page.)
  - See the **bottom section** for how to make the command `more` / the `help` function in PowerShell use `less` instead of `more.com`, via a **custom `more` function that also ensures use of UTF-8 encoding**.
- **GnuWin `less.exe` version `394`** (current as of this writing, but published in 2006-01-03) **sometimes acts erratically** and displays *nothing*; starting a new session makes the problem go away.

---

The - less powerful (no pun intended) - **Windows counterpart to `less` is `more` (`more.com`)**, which accepts text via stdin / the pipeline or via a filename arguments.

Remarkably, **`more.com` only seems to support paging *down***, with <kbd>space</kbd>, and not back up; that is, you can't scroll *back* - see [here](https://www.computerhope.com/morehlp.htm).

PowerShell's own **`Out-Host -Paging` has the same limitation**.

- *Windows PowerShell* provides a built-in wrapper function around `more.com` also named `more` (which means that executing just `more` executes the *function*), which ensures that the content of specified files is output with the encoding of the active OEM code page, which is what `more.com` expects.
- PowerShell [Core] 6+ doesn't provide this wrapper anymore.

In both editions, the built-in `help` function, which itself wraps `Get-Help`, implicitly pipes the latter's output to `more` - invariably in Windows PowerShell, by default in PowerShell 6+ on Windows (on Unix, it defaults to `less`.

In PowerShell 6+, you can also define a custom pager by setting the `$env:PAGER` variable to the command line you want invoked for paging `help` output.

In Windows PowerShell, your only option is to replace / define a custom `more` function (which would also work in PowerShell 6+).

In other words: Something like the following gives you interactively paged output *by default*:

```
help Get-ChildItem  # Effectively the same as: Get-Help Get-ChildItem | more
```

---

#### If you have `less` available on Windows and want to use it instead of `more`:

Overwrite the built-in / define a `more` function as follows (in your `$PROFILE` file):

- Use of `less` via WSL:

```
# Via WSL
function more { 
  $prevOe, $prevCoe = $OutputEncoding, [console]::OutputEncoding
  try {
    $OutputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Utf8Encoding]::new()
    $Input | wsl less
  }
  finally {
    $OutputEncoding, [console]::OutputEncoding = $prevOe, $prevCoe
  }
}

# If running PowerShell Core (v6+):
# Force the `help` function to use the custom function.
if ($IsCoreClr) { $env:PAGER = 'more' }
```

- Use of GnuWin `less.exe`:

```
# Via GnuWin (assuming the default installation location)
function more { 
  $prevOe, $prevCoe = $OutputEncoding, [console]::OutputEncoding
  try {
    $OutputEncoding = [console]::OutputEncoding = [Text.Utf8Encoding]::new()
    $Input | & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\less.exe'
  }
  finally {
    $OutputEncoding, [console]::OutputEncoding = $prevOe, $prevCoe
  }
}

# If running PowerShell Core (v6+):
# Force the `help` function to use the custom function.
if ($IsCoreClr) { $env:PAGER = 'more' }
```

Note: This makes `more` only accept *pipeline* input, but it wouldn't be hard to extend the function to accept filename arguments too.

---

***If* the following conditions are met**, there is a **simpler solution**, suggested by [David Hatch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5012323/david-hatch):

- You have GnuWin `less.exe` installed.
- You don't need support for non-ASCII characters.
- You do, but your sessions are already configured to set both `$OutputEncoding` and `[console]::OutputEncoding` to UTF-8. (`$OutputEncoding` defaults to UTF-8 in PowerShell [Core] v6+, but not `[console]::OutputEncoding]`).

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49481797/45375) for how to switch your PowerShell sessions to use UTF-8 consistently, via `$PROFILE`.
  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) for how to configure Windows 10 *system-wide* to use code page `65001` == UTF-8, but note that the feature is still in beta as of this writing, and that it has side effects and limitations; notably, it makes *Windows PowerShell* commands that use the active ANSI code page (`Get-Content` / `Set-Content`) then default to UTF-8.

Windows PowerShell:

```
Set-Alias more 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\less.exe'
```

PowerShell [Core] v6+:

```
$env:PAGER = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\less.exe'
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to answer by [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59240939/3970623) and in case of you have none of the tools installed but a version of python and pip, it may be another working solution to install the pypager package and alias to it:

```
> pip install pypager
> New-Alias less pypager
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that "less"i and "more" can work normally. After querying, I found the reason is that cygwin was installed.

```
❯ Get-Command more

CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     more.exe                                           

❯ Get-Command less                                                                                                                                                                                              CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     less.exe                                           0.0.0.0    C:\cygwin64\bin\less.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

This is partly a reply to "if_ok_button", but can't fit into a sub-comment but I use the following (slightly elaborate) function that has now become a fixture in my toolkit, if I run "def " *or* object type, like a variable, it will return me a summary of all information about that thing without me having to find the right command - I've been building it up and it covers a lot quite nicely now (but if anyone has any improvements, I would appreciate that).

e.g.
def dir, def more, def abc, def get-command, def gc, def

```
# Find definitions for any Cmdlet, Function, Alias, External Script, Application
function def {   
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ArgumentCompleter({ [Management.Automation.CompletionResult]::Command })]
        [string]$cmd,
        [switch]$Examples
    )

    function Write-Wrap {
        [CmdletBinding()]Param( [parameter(Mandatory=1, ValueFromPipeline=1, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=1)] [Object[]]$chunk )
        $Lines = @()
        foreach ($line in $chunk) {
            $str = ''; $counter = 0
            $line -split '\s+' | % {
                $counter += $_.Length + 1
                if ($counter -gt $Host.UI.RawUI.BufferSize.Width) {
                    $Lines += ,$str.trim()
                    $str = ''
                    $counter = $_.Length + 1
                }
                $str = "$str$_ "
            }
            $Lines += ,$str.trim()
        }
        $Lines
    }

    $deferr = 0; $type = ""
    try { $type = ((gcm $cmd -EA silent).CommandType); if ($null -eq $type) { $deferr = 1 } } catch { $deferr = 1 }

    if ($deferr -eq 1) {
        if ($cmd -eq $null) { Write-Host "Object is `$null" ; return } 
        Write-Host "`$object | Convert-Json:" -F Cyan
        $cmd | ConvertTo-Json
        ""
        Write-Host "(`$object).GetType()" -F Cyan -NoNewline ; Write-Host " :: [BaseType|Name|IsPublic|IsSerial|Module]"
        ($cmd).GetType() | % { "$($_.BaseType), $($_.Name), $($_.IsPublic), $($_.IsSerializable), $($_.Module)" }
        ""
        Write-Host "`$object | Get-Member -Force" -F Cyan
        $m = "" ; $cm = "" ; $sm = ""; $p = "" ; $ap = "" ; $cp = "" ; $np = "" ; $pp = "" ; $sp = "" ; $ms = ""
        $msum = 0 ; $cmsum = 0 ; $smsum = 0 ; $psum = 0 ; $cpsum = 0 ; $apsum = 0 ; $spsum = 0 ; $ppsum = 0 ; $npsum = 0 ; $spsum = 0 ; $mssum = 0
        $($cmd | Get-Member -Force) | % {
            if ($_.MemberType -eq "Method") { if(!($m -like "*$($_.Name),*")) { $m += "$($_.Name), " ; $msum++ } }
            if ($_.MemberType -eq "CodeMethod") { if(!($cm -like "*$($_.Name),*")) { $cm += "$($_.Name), " ; $cmsum++ } }
            if ($_.MemberType -eq "ScriptMethod") { if(!($sm -like "*$($_.Name),*")) { $sm += "$($_.Name), " ; $smsum++ } }
            if ($_.MemberType -eq "Property") { if(!($p -like "*$($_.Name),*")) { $p += "$($_.Name), " ; $psum++ } }
            if ($_.MemberType -eq "AliasProperty") { if(!($ap -like "*$($_.Name),*")) { $ap += "$($_.Name), " ; $apsum++ } }
            if ($_.MemberType -eq "CodeProperty") { if(!($cp -like "*$($_.Name),*")) { $cp += "$($_.Name), " ; $cpsum++ } }
            if ($_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty") { if(!($np -like "*$($_.Name),*")) { $np += "$($_.Name), " ; $npsum++ } }
            if ($_.MemberType -eq "ParameterizedProperty") { if(!($pp -like "*$($_.Name),*")) { $pp += "$($_.Name), " ; $ppsum++} }
            if ($_.MemberType -eq "ScriptProperty") { if(!($sp -like "*$($_.Name),*")) { $sp += "$($_.Name), " ; $npsum++ } }
            if ($_.MemberType -eq "MemberSet") { if(!($ms -like "*$($_.Name),*")) { $ms += "$($_.Name), " ; $mssum++ } }
            # AliasProperty, CodeMethod, CodeProperty, Method, NoteProperty, ParameterizedProperty, Property, ScriptMethod, ScriptProperty
            # All, Methods, MemberSet, Properties, PropertySet
        }
        if($msum -ne 0) { Write-Wrap ":: Method [$msum] => $($m.TrimEnd(", "))" }
        if($msum -ne 0) { Write-Wrap ":: CodeMethod [$cmsum] => $($cm.TrimEnd(", "))" }
        if($msum -ne 0) { Write-Wrap ":: ScriptMethod [$smsum] => $($sm.TrimEnd(", "))" }
        if($psum -ne 0) { Write-Wrap ":: Property [$psum] => $($p.TrimEnd(", "))" }
        if($npsum -ne 0) { Write-Wrap ":: AliasProperty [$apsum] => $($ap.TrimEnd(", "))" }
        if($npsum -ne 0) { Write-Wrap ":: CodeProperty [$cpsum] => $($cp.TrimEnd(", "))" }
        if($npsum -ne 0) { Write-Wrap ":: NoteProperty [$npsum] => $($np.TrimEnd(", "))" }
        if($ppsum -ne 0) { Write-Wrap ":: ParameterizedProperty [$ppsum] => $($pp.TrimEnd(", "))" }
        if($spsum -ne 0) { Write-Wrap ":: ScriptProperty [$spsum] => $($sp.TrimEnd(", "))" }
        if($mssum -ne 0) { Write-Wrap ":: ScriptProperty [$mssum] => $($ms.TrimEnd(", "))" }
        ""
        Write-Host "`$object | Measure-Object" -F Cyan
        $cmd | Measure-Object | % { "Count [$($_.Count)], Average [$($_.Average)], Sum [$($_.Sum)], Maximum [$($_.Maximum)], Minimum [$($_.Minimum)], Property [$($_.Property)]" }
    }

    if ($deferr -eq 0) {

        if ($cmd -like '*`**') { Get-Command $cmd ; break }   # If $cmd contains a *, then just check for commands, don't find definitions
   
        if ($type -eq 'Cmdlet') {
            Write-Host "`n'$cmd' is a Cmdlet:`n" -F Green
            Write-Host "SYNOPSIS, DESCRIPTION, SYNTAX for '$cmd'.   " -F Green
            Write-Host "------------"
            Write-Host ""
            Write-Host "(Get-Help $cmd).Synopsis" -F Cyan 
            Write-Host "$((Get-Help $cmd).Synopsis)"
            Write-Host ""
            Write-Host "(Get-Help $cmd).Description.Text" -F Cyan
            try {
                $arrdescription = (Get-Help $cmd).Description.Text.split("`n")
                foreach ($i in $arrdescription) { Write-Wrap $i }
            } catch { "Could not resolve description for $cmd" }
            Write-Host ""
            Write-Host "(Get-Command $cmd -Syntax)" -F Cyan
            $arrsyntax = (Get-Command $cmd -syntax).TrimStart("").Split("`n")  # Trim empty first line then split by line breaks
            foreach ($i in $arrsyntax) { Write-Wrap $i }   # Wrap lines properly to console width
            Get-Alias -definition $cmd -EA silent          # Show all defined aliases
            Write-Host "`nThis Cmdlet is in the '$((Get-Command -type cmdlet $cmd).Source)' Module." -F Green
            Write-Host ""
            Write-Host ""
        }
        elseif ($type -eq 'Alias') {
            Write-Host "`n'$cmd' is an Alias.  " -F Green -NoNewLine ; Write-Host "This Alias is in the '$((get-command -type alias $cmd).ModuleName).' Module"
            Write-Host ""
            Write-Host "Get-Alias '$cmd'   *or*    cat alias:\$cmd" -F Cyan
            cat alias:\$cmd   # Write-Host "$(cat alias:\$cmd)"   # "$((Get-Alias $cmd -EA silent).definition)"
            if ($cmd -eq '?') { $cmd = '`?' }   # To deal correctly with the wildcard '?'
            "`n'$((Get-Alias $cmd).Name)' is an alias of '$((Get-Alias $cmd).ReferencedCommand)'"
            $fulldef = (Get-Alias $cmd -EA silent).definition   # Rerun def but using the full cmdlet or function name.
            def $fulldef
            if ($Examples -eq $true) { $null = Read-Host 'Press any key to view command examples' ; get-help $fulldef -examples }
        }
        elseif ($type -eq 'Function') {
            Write-Host "`n'$cmd' is a Function.  " -F Green -NoNewline
            Write-Host "`ncat function:\$cmd   (show contents of function)`n" -F Cyan ; cat function:\$cmd ; Write-Host ""
            Write-Host "cat function:\$cmd`n" -F Cyan
            Write-Host ""
            Write-Host "SYNOPSIS, SYNTAX for '$cmd'.   " -F Green
            Write-Host "------------"
            $arrsynopsis = ((Get-Help $cmd).Synopsis).TrimStart("").Split("`n")  # Trim empty first line then split by line breaks
            $arrsyntax = (Get-Command $cmd -syntax).TrimStart("").Split("`n")    # Often synopsis=syntax for function so use Compare-Object
            if ($null -eq $(Compare-Object $arrsynopsis $arrsyntax -SyncWindow 0)) { 
                Write-Host "'(Get-Help $cmd).Synopsis'" -F Cyan -N
                Write-Host " and " -N
                Write-Host "'Get-Command $cmd -Syntax'" -F Cyan -N
                Write-Host " have the same output for this function:`n"
                foreach ($i in $arrsynopsis) { Write-Wrap $i }   # Wrap lines properly to console width
            } else { 
                Write-Host "(Get-Help $cmd).Synopsis" -F Cyan
                foreach ($i in $arrsynopsis) { Write-Wrap $i }   # Wrap lines properly to console width
                Write-Host ""
                Write-Host "Get-Command $cmd -Syntax" -F Cyan
                foreach ($i in $arrsyntax) { Write-Wrap $i }     # Wrap lines properly to console width
            }
            Write-Host "The '$cmd' Function is in the '$((get-command -type function $cmd).Source)' Module." -F Green
            Write-Host ""
            if ($Examples -eq $true) { $null = Read-Host "Press any key to view command examples" ; get-help $cmd -examples }
            Write-Host ""
        }
        elseif ($type -eq 'ExternalScript') {   # For .ps1 scripts on path
            $x = gcm $cmd
            Write-Host "`n'$cmd' is an ExternalScript (i.e. a .ps1 file on the path)." -F Green
            Write-Host "`n$($x.Path)`n" -F Green
            Write-Host "`n$($x.ScriptContents)"
            Write-Host ""
            if ($Examples -eq $true) { $null = Read-Host "Press any key to view command examples" ; get-help $cmd -Examples }
            elseif ($Synopsis -eq $true) { $null = Read-Host "Press any key to view command examples" ; (get-help $cmd).Synopsis }
            elseif ($Syntax -eq $true) { $null = Read-Host "Press any key to view command examples" ; Get-Command $cmd -Syntax }
            Write-Host ""
        }
        elseif ($type -eq 'Application') {      # For .exe etc on path
            Write-Host "`n'$cmd' was found. It is an Application (i.e. a .exe or similar located on the path)." -F Green
            Write-Host "`n$(where.exe $cmd)" -F Green
            Write-Host ""
            Read-Host "Press any key to open cmd.exe and try '$cmd /?'" ; cmd.exe /c $cmd /? | more
            Write-Host ""
        }
    } elseif ((get-module -ListAvailable -Name $cmd) -ne $null) {
        # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28740320/how-do-i-check-if-a-powershell-module-is-installed
        ""
        (get-module $cmd).path
        (get-module $cmd).ExportedFunctions
        "ExportedCommands (also note: get-command -Module $cmd)"
        (get-module custom-tools).ExportedCommands
        ""
        echo "get-module $cmd | get-member  # Just show the members"
        echo "get-module $cmd | fl *        # Show the contents of every member"
    }
    else {
        if ($cmd.length -eq 0) { "`n'$cmd': No command definition found. The command may require to be surround by ' or `"`nif it contains special characters (such as 'def `"&`"').`n" }
        else { "`nInput is not a command, so no command definition search.`n" }
    }
}
```